# Playback mp3s in Symbian Belle with J2ME

Tags: mp3, symbian, audio-player

i`m new to Symbian , my goal is to playback mp3 file stored on phone with my MIDLet.
Is it possible? I do not know how to do it - i'll be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with the APIs provided by J2ME.

First step. You need to verify that your specific phone has the capabilities required. Install any free J2ME mp3 app like KD Player (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KD_Player) and try using it on your phone.

Second step. If your phone can play mp3 music using the free app but you still want to create your own, you need to find a good J2ME resource like this:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/index-156363.html

To be honest, that second step is probably a bit too much especially if you're the kind of person who asks first instead of using Google. Sorry.

Comment: if I found the answer in Google, I would not asked this question here) but thanks ,  I'll try your solution.